# How to drop duplicate documents of a sharded indices in mongo?

Tags: mongodb, duplicates

I sharded a mongo cluster on a key ("link"); indexing it but failing to ensure uniqueness. After ingesting more data, I have duplicates documents of my sharded field. (duplicate links).  Is there a command to drop the duplicates? I'm assuming you can't after attempting to run this command

```
db.articles.ensureIndex({"link" : 1}, {unique : true, dropDups : true});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is not direct command other than the one you've already tried. Ideally you would drop and re-create this collection, specifying that the shard key is unique, and then reload the data:

```
db.runCommand( { shardCollection : "articles" , key : { link : 1 } , unique : true } );
```

There is a good write up of the various approaches to ensuring uniqueness on sharded collections in the documentation:

http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/enforce-unique-keys-for-sharded-collections/

Overall you could remove the dups via a custom bit of javascript in the shell and then use proxy collection with a unique index (as discussed in the above link) to enforce uniqueness going forward.